# Firebase data payload messages remove special characters from string for some reason

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
{  
"to" : "required token..",  
"notification" : {  
      "body" : "great match!",   
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",  
      "icon" : "myicon"  
    },  
"data": {  
    "id": 1,  
    "action": "load_content",  
    "frequency": 1,  

    "payload": "{\"module\":\"news\",\"id\":32}"
}  
}
```

Code:

```
payload = data.get("payload");
Log.i(TAG, " received payload =" + payload);
```

When I extract the payload that I'm sending as a string and put it out on the logcat I get

> **{"module":"news","id":32}**

I would want to keep the string as it is sent (with the '/' in it). I'm not really sure why that's happening. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want this for? What you are describing sounds pretty much a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The payload string would be attached further to a javascript which is why I need the special characters to be in there.
  final String javascript = "function_name(\"key\","+ payload+")";
  which would eventually be used in 
  webview.evaluateJavascript(javascript..

Comment: How are you saving this? Why don't you just save it as a JSON and not a string?

Comment: for the key which is "payload" the value is a String, which is "{\"module\":\"news\",\"id\":32}". I'm not sure how I could store the value as a JSON and why you're suggesting so. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are only escaping the double quote with \" if you want to retain the backslash you will also have to escape that with \. So your resulting field would look like:

```
"payload": "{\\\"module\\\":\\\"news\\\",\\\"id\\\":32}"
```

That should result in output that looks like:

```
{\"module\":\"news\",\"id\":32}
```

Comment: The payload is passing just a string and FCM, which I'm using, shouldn't really be concerned with what I put inside a string per se. What you suggested is correct but the I cannot change what will be sent from the server. I'm wondering why FCM would change any of my data even after it is enclosed in double quotes and passed as a string.

Comment: Your payload has to be interpreted as a Java String which has rules about including double quotes and backslashes. If you define a string as 
"{\"module\":\"news\",\"id\":32}" it will be interpreted as 
"{"module":"news","id":32}" which matches what you are seeing